# Trying to access `splits['test']` but `splits` is empty. This likely indicate the dataset has not been generated yet

Tags: tensorflow, document

When I try to run the 'Adjust the training configuration' code section in docs\vision\image_classification.ipynb, I see the error 'Trying to access `splits['test']` but `splits` is empty. This likely indicate the dataset has not been generated yet.'

I see that spilts in dataset_info of tensorflow_datasets is empty when using the 'cifar10'.
Would like to know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
dataset, ds_info = tfds.load('cifar10',
                             split=['train', 'test'],
                             shuffle_files=True,
                             as_supervised=True,
                             with_info=True,)

print(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
print(ds_info.splits['test'].num_examples)
```

Output:

```
50000
10000
```